# Stopping Iframe from taking over the page

Tags: html, iframe

I have an Iframe in my code and some of the source URLs take over the page, how can I stop this behavior? is there a skipping mechanism or Iframe disabling mechanism?

Comment: can you provide us with an image or example so we know what you are getting?

Comment: If someone don't want you to put their webpage in an iframe, you probably shouldn't...